# VBA code that will look for certain criteria and if it matches place data from a different column into a another one

Tags: excel, vba, loops, offset

I need help with a VBA code that will look for certain criteria and if it matches place data from a different column into a another one.

If column C says "Circum + spa" and D says "100" then the values in row F need to move over two columns to H 
until column C says "Circum + spa" and D says "0" (where it will stay in column F.) 
finished result will looks like a snake.

The code I have started with this process with is:

```
    Dim l As Long
    With ActiveSheet
        l = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp).Row
        For i = 1 To l
            If .Cells(i, "C").Value2 = "CIRCUM + SPA" And 
            .Cells(i, "D") = "100" Then
            .Cells(i + 1, "F").Value = .Cells(i + 1, "H").Value
        Next
    End With
```

But currently it just makes one row down in column F empty... I have also attempted cut/paste and an offset but all I get are error messages.

I also know that using +1 isn't going to work in final result because I need it to grab everything until the other condition is met.

I have not started on that yet, but would appreciate any advise on a Do-Until loop.

I have attached pictures of what my worksheet looks like now vs what I need it to look like after the macro runs. Also, the rows that move will not always contain 4 cells, sometimes there will be more that's why I need the do until rather than a set range.

[before](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fRRaw.jpg)[1]
[after](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FrDOB.jpg) (2)

Comment: For starters, it looks like you're missing an `End If` in your loop.

Comment: also, .Cells(i + 1, "H").Value = .Cells(i + 1, "F").Value will get values in H Col. And why you are checking i and entering data in i+1.Is that the requirement

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
Sub Demo()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim cel As Range, fCell As Range, lCell As Range
    Dim lastRow As Long
    Dim flag As Boolean

    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet4")      'change Sheet4 to your data sheet
    flag = False

    With ws
        lastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp).Row    'last row with data in Column C

        For Each cel In .Range("C2:C" & lastRow)   'loop through each cell in Column C
            If UCase(cel.Value) = "CIRCUM + SPA" Then   'check if Command Name is "CIRCUM + SPA"
                If cel.Offset(, 1).Value = 100 Then     'check if SP is 100
                    Set fCell = cel.Offset(1, 0)        'set first cell to be copied in fCell
                    flag = True
                ElseIf cel.Offset(, 1).Value = 0 Then   'check if SP is 0
                    If flag Then                        'move ahead only if ("CIRCUM + SPA" & 100) already found
                        Set lCell = cel.Offset(-1, 0)   'set last cell to be copied in lCell
                        Set rng = .Range(fCell, lCell).Offset(, 3)  'set range using fCell and lCell
                        rng.Cut rng.Offset(, 2)         'move data from Column F to Column H
                        flag = False
                    End If
                End If
            End If
        Next cel
    End With
End Sub
```

[image]